# Graphing multiple disk volumes in Nagiosgraph

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nagios

I want to graph free disk space for all /dev/ volumes on a server in a single nagiosgraph.I have been following a tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nagios-plugins-with-ruby-on-ubuntu-12-10)

This tutorial uses a Ruby script to check the entire disk structure using this code:

```
used_space=`df -h / | grep -v "Filesystem" | awk '{print $5}'`
```

I have two questions, how to best dynamically determine which volumes a server has and then how to output the free space for each volume to nagios perfdata in a way that I can get a line for each volume on the server.

Here is my complete script - thanks for the answer below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def largest_hash_key(hash)
  hash.max_by{|k,v| v}
end

filesystem = %x(df -h)

perfdata = filesystem.split("\n")
                 .grep(/\A\/dev/)
                 .map(&:split)
                 .map{ |e| "'%s'=%s" % [ e[-1], e[-2] ] }
                 .join(" ")

volumes = Hash[perfdata.split(" ").map {|str| str.split("=")}]

volumes = volumes.map{ |k, v| [k, v.to_i] }

full_disk = largest_hash_key(volumes)

pc_full = full_disk[1]

message = "#{perfdata} | #{perfdata}" 

if pc_full > 94
   puts "DISK CRITICAL - #{message}"
   exit 2
elsif pc_full > 89
   puts "DISK WARNING - #{message}"
   exit 1
else
   puts "DISK OK - #{message}"
   exit 0   
end
```

Comment: This is primarily a sysadmin question. I'd vote to close if not for the bounty.

Comment: The solution I am looking for is a Ruby script.

Comment: So you are looking for a pure Ruby script (not shell executed inside Ruby) outputting free space for each volume, one line per volume? Or can we assume you are on Linux and executing shell commands is fine?

Comment: Yes, executing shell commands is file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: joining with spaces instead of new lines, see markhorrocks comment below.**

Assuming your script is running on a Linux machine and [this](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN200) is the format you are referring to by nagios perfdata, you could write:

```
%x(df -h)
  .split("\n")
  .grep(/\A\/dev/)
  .map(&:split)
  .map{ |e| "'%s'=%s" % [ e[0], e[-2] ] }
  .join(" ")
```

which will output

```
'/dev/sda3'=50%
```

Comment: .map{ |e| "'%s'=%s" % [ e[-1], e[-2] ] } looks a little better

Comment: Joining with new lines prevented the nagiosgraph map default rule from graphing more than one volume, joining on a space fixed it.